# Projectile motion question : time at which velocity v becomes perpendicular to initial velocity u?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, kinematics, projectile

A projectile is thrown up with the initial speed u, making an angle theta (theta > 45 deg) with the horizontal. What is the time, just after which, it will be moving perpendicular to its initial direction of motion?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer ​​
homework or worked example **type** questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/75633) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/75633). You might want to consider posting [some other Physics website](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/391/75633)​, such as t​he [PhysicsForums](https://www.physicsforums.com/forums/homework-and-coursework-questions.152/).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in stafusa's comment I'm not going to give the answer, but instead a hint.

You could try thinking about the individual components of velocity (vertical and horizontal) as a function of time.